# How can you include the delimiter in a .split string in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a String as follows:

```
var _quotedText = "Text1[John;1234]Text2";
```

Which I want to split into a list as follows:

```
final List<String> _splitQuotedText = _quotedText.split(RegExp(r"\[([A-z].+);([0-9]+)\]"));
```

My list comes out as:

```
['Text1', 'Text2']
```

But I'd like it to actually comes out as:

```
['Text1', '[John;1234]Text2']
```

Meaning the delimiter should be included with the match, and ideally the delimiter would be considered the "start" for a given item.

Is there any kind of straightforward way to tackle this?

Comment: A delimiter is by definition going to be removed when you do a split. So you may need to reconstruct it if you use a '[' for the split or write your own splitting algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use regex's lookahead function.

A lookahead will match whatever is before your lookahead, we can use it to match the space before your delimiter and use that as a delimiter:

A lookahead looks like this:

```
(?= ... )
```

So your new regex looks like this:

```
(?=\[([A-z].+);([0-9]+)\])
```

Here is your example:

```
void main() {
  var myString = "Text1[John;1234]Text2";
  List<String> myList = myString.split(RegExp(r"(?=\[([A-z].+);([0-9]+)\])"));

  print(myList); // ['Text1', '[John;1234]Text2']
}
```